# ordinal axis not updating on data filtering in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I have 4 charts in dc.js. One of the charts has ordinal data displayed. I want the chart to display the data selected by the user which is working fine. But I want the axis to display ordinal values of only the selected data. Is there any way to do so. I am using

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(group.all()
                            .map(function(d){ 
                                return d.key; })))
```

and setting

```
.elasticX(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the ordinal domain yourself in dc.js 2.0 and greater.

What is probably happening here is that the bins are still there but they have value zero - crossfilter doesn't remove empty bins.

You might try wrapping your group with this:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted